# Two separate file extensions have become linked

Tags: windows, registry, file-type

(System: Windows 10)

Somehow I have got the "scss" extension and "js" extension associated together in the same way that ".htm" and ".html" refer to the same file type.

As I use SASS, I added the ".scss" extension to Dreamweaver so that the program could recognise it but somehow the ".scss" and ".js" extensions got linked.

If I open "Default Programs Editor" and try to change the icon, it shows:
"Description: JS file - Extensions of this type: .js, .scss". So now SCSS files and JS files show the same icon. Not vitally important but annoying.

Does anyone know how to separate the two extensions so that they are no longer associated?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes here with a similar problem, I finally found the answer by experiment.

Take either of the linked extension and set the file to open by default in another program (it doesn't matter which). This will change the icon of that file type. Then set it to open by default in the original program. The two extensions will now be separate.